# Plot jqplot graph from json data

Tags: javascript, php, json, jqplot

i have a php backend

```
$query = "SELECT value FROM changes WHERE stock_id={$id}";
$results = mysql_query($query, $connection);

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
 $values[]=$row['value'];
 }
echo  json_encode($values);
```

and this is my javascript

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'data.php',
        data: {id: stock},
        type: 'get',
        success: function(data) {
        $.jqplot ('graph-container', data);
        }
    });
```

the console shows no data specified error

Note: im using a one dimentional array ie, i expect array like [25,15,3656,65]

Comment: in success try `console.log(data)` to check data is coming or not.

Comment: @Gowri this is what im getting in console ["272.71","272.71","272.71","272.71","272.71"]

Comment: Did you give your HTML target a width and a height?

Comment: You will have to convert the string values to float either before you encode in the backend or when you receive it at the client.

Comment: @mccannf i did in php now im getting [272.71,272.71,272.71,272.71,272.71], still no graph same error.

Comment: @isim yes, i have given width and height

Comment: If this is a single series, the I would change the jqplot command to `$.jqplot ('graph-container', [data]);`

Answer (score 0):

Ok i kept fiddling and i fixed it

change in php:

```
echo  json_encode(Array($values));
```

i added a Array function,

change in jscript:

```
data=JSON.parse(data);
```

i was not parsing it back to array.